# MPAndroidChart invisible dataset can still be highlighted

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library version 2.1.0 and I have a line chart with 8 or so Datasets and it works great.
Now I'm trying to temporary hide all Datasets except the one selected/highlighted by the user and show them again once the selection is cleared. For this I'm using the `OnValueSelected` and `OnNothingSelected` callbacks to make all Datasets invisible (`setVisible(false)`) except the selected one. This is working to an extend.
The problem is that the invisible datasets can still be selected/highlighted in the places where they used to be (which is indicated by the Marker View).
How can I prevent the invisible Datasets from being selected/highlighted?
Am I even taking the right approach here? I did not want to completely delete the Datasets since they will be shown again once the selection is cleared.
Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you discovered a bug. That should indeed not be possible. I will look into it and provide a fix as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Please let me know if you need any help simulating the problem. For now I've solved my issue by disabling the touches on the graph and using a custom legend to hide/show the datasets.